# Ошибка компиляции .exe из .py

Tags: python, компиляция, exe, pyinstaller

Пытался компилировать и через **cx_freeze** и через **pyinstaller**.

Во время самого процесса выдает кучу строк типа `WARNING: lib not found: *...*`, а потом `completed successfully`

При запуске самого .exe открывается консоль секунд на 5 с сообщением

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002da4 (most recent call first):
```

Сам питон последней версии, **pyinstaller** и все сопутствующее установлено через pip.

p.s Если запускать через IDE с `import encodings` то никакой ошибки нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.7 не поддерживается ещё pyinstaller'ом. [Источник](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3219)

Comment: На гитхабе, в описании, написано поддерживается, или я чего-то не понимаю? https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

Comment: Эта ошибка возникает с python3.7. Попробуйте откатиться до 3.6